# Automated Process User

Tags: visual-workflow

I created a new flow that sends out email messages to the end-customer and also creates follow up tasks for the agents working in our system.

The flow replaces and older flow, with pretty much the same entry criteria, creation resources, etc.. However, the CreatedById for the created tasks is no longer "Automated Process" but now uses the Default Workflow User.

Any idea how this happened and how to revert this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [new feature in Winter 22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_versioned_updates.htm&type=5&release=234) that allows you to specify default workflow user, and that user will be used in Scheduled flows.  Per the docs if you do not specify one, then autoproc user will be used.

I've never found a benefit to autoproc, as it can run into issues assigning apex class access, etc. I guess it does save a user license.

> **Specify the default workflow user to run schedule-triggered flows** 
>  Now you can specify the default workflow user in your org’s
> process automation settings to run schedule-triggered flows.
> Previously, the Automated Process user ran schedule-triggered flows.
> If you don’t specify the default workflow user to run
> schedule-triggered flows, the Automated Process user runs them by
> default instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an updated summary](https://unofficialsf.com/understanding-the-automated-process-user-the-default-workflow-user/) of how Automated Process User and Default Workflow User work with Flow. In general Default Workflow User is superior in its flexibility.